# How to check / determine session age using PHP

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I wonder if it's possible to check session age somehow with PHP. I have browsed trough stackoverflow and have not found anything. Thanks for all answers in advance.

*In case anyone wonder why would I need to know something like this is, I want to show notification on top of the screen on all pages for all people are logged in less then 30 minutes.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just set `$_SESSION['logged_in_at'] = time()` when the user logs in, then check `if( time() - $_SESSION['logged_in_at'] < 30*60)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$session_time = fileatime(session_save_path()."/sess_".session_id());
echo "Session Age (Seconds): ".(time()-$session_time);
```

Perhaps it isn't best practice but it'll do, in the absence of a native function like `session_time()`.

Comment: This will give the session idle time, since you are looking at the time of last access. Which will be 0 all the time, since you are in a session, otherwise session_id() is not defined.

Comment: In PHP 8.1 I tried with filectime with the same result, so this doesn't work for me.