# How can make automatic logout in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I make web with login/logout.

If any link or button pressed on web I call ajax function to check login and if time expired logout user. In logout function I update my database.

But If I close browser or page user is not logged out and database is not updated. How can I add event listener for it.

PHP FILE

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($action) {
        case "checkLogin":
            echo isLogged();
            break;
        case "logout":
            logout();
            break;
         //and more
    }
}

function isLogged() {
    $data = array(
        "login"     => 0,
        "username" => "null"
    );

    if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) && isset($_SESSION["start"])) {
        $session_start = $_SESSION["start"];
        //more then 600 sec
        if(time() - $session_start < 600){
            $data = array(
                "login"     => 1,
                "username" => $_SESSION["user"]
            );
        }else{
            logout();
        }
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}

function logout(){
    if(isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
        $connection = connectToDB();
        if($connection != null) {
            $nickname = $_SESSION["user"];
            $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $sql_statement = "UPDATE users SET is_login='0',last_login='$time' WHERE username='$nickname';";
            $connection->query($sql_statement);
        }
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would suggest either checking periodically to see if anyone has exceeded the time, or just check the next time they visit the site.  There is the on unload event or whatever, but that doesn't handle for the case that the user just hard poweroff's their pc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no surefire way to "listen" for the user closing your window or, as @Taplar pointed out, powering off their computer. Using the technique of storing the login time within the session described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093368/how-to-check-determine-session-age-using-php), you can run a cron or other kind of background task checking the database for sessions that are due to expire, and then expire them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **unload** listener with **async** - false, so browser will wait while request is not finished:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/logout',
        async: false
    });
});
```

Note that browser will "hang" during request, and it can confuse user